# ASP.NET Core 3.1 map multiple datasets to one table

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I need to map many view models to one table.

Table:

```cs
[Table("BaseTable")]
public class baseTable
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public byte[] FullText { get; set; }
    public byte[] FullText1 { get; set; }
}

[Table("BaseTable")]
public class baseTableTitle
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

[Table("BaseTable")]
public class baseTableFullText
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public byte[] FullText { get; set; }
}

[Table("BaseTable")]
public class baseTableFullText1
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public byte[] FullText1 { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext:

```cs
public class myDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<BaseTable> BaseTable { get; set; };
    public DbSet<baseTableTitle> BaseTableTitle { get; set; };
    public DbSet<BaseTableFullText> BaseTableFullText { get; set; };
    public DbSet<BaseTableFullText1> BaseTableFullText1 { get; set; };
}
```

And I get a runtime error:

> Cannot use table 'BaseTable' for entity type 'BaseTableTitle' since it is being used for entity type 'BaseTable' and there is no relationship between their primary keys.

How can I map many datasets to one table?

Expexcted usage:

> baseTable - read, write

> baseTable(Title, FullText, FullText1) - read only

Comment: Have you read about Table-per-Type and Table-per-Hierarchy yet? Have a look at [Entity Framework - Inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance).

Answer (score 0):

You do not need that. Leave only one `baseTable` mapped to database. Other should be as DTO.

```cs
[Table("BaseTable")]
public class baseTable
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public byte[] FullText { get; set; }
    public byte[] FullText1 { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext

```cs
public class myDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<BaseTable> BaseTable { get; set; }
}
```

DTO classes:

```cs
public class baseTableTitle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class baseTableFullText
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public byte[] FullText { get; set; }
}

public class baseTableFullText1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public byte[] FullText1 { get; set; }
}
```

And helper extensions:

```cs
public static class myDbContextViews
{
    public IQueryable<baseTableTitle> BaseTableTitle(this myDbContext ctx) 
       => ctx.BaseTable.Select(x => new baseTableTitle { Id = x.Id, Title = x.Title };

    public IQueryable<BaseTableFullText> BaseTableFullText(this myDbContext ctx) 
       => ctx.BaseTable.Select(x => new BaseTableFullText { Id = x.Id, Title = x.Title, FullText = x.FullText };

    public IQueryable<BaseTableFullText1> BaseTableFullText1(this myDbContext ctx) 
       => ctx.BaseTable.Select(x => new BaseTableFullText1 { Id = x.Id, Title = x.Title, FullText1 = x.FullText1 };
}
```